# MpAndroidChart Pie chart with rounded corners

Tags: android, charts, material-design, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to draw a pie chart with rounded corners using MpAndroidChart library.

Expected output is something similar to this.

[image]

Both ends need to be outer round. There is a method pieChart.setDrawRoundedSlices(true), but the issue is start point of the pie chart getting inner round.

This is the actual output.

[image]

```
// initialise pie chart UI
fun initChart(mChart: PieChart) {
    mChart.description.isEnabled = false
    mChart.holeRadius = 75f
    mChart.transparentCircleRadius = 60f
    mChart.setHoleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    mChart.legend.isEnabled = false
    mChart.isRotationEnabled = false
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(false)
    mChart.maxAngle = 270f
    mChart.rotation = -135f
    mChart.animateX(400)
    mChart.setDrawRoundedSlices(true)
}
```

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Is there anyway to archive this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was faced with the same challenge recently, this is the code of the renderer in case anyone may need it:

```
public class RoundedSlicesPieChartRenderer extends PieChartRenderer {
    public RoundedSlicesPieChartRenderer(PieChart chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);

        chart.setDrawRoundedSlices(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IPieDataSet dataSet) {
        float angle = 0;
        float rotationAngle = mChart.getRotationAngle();

        float phaseX = mAnimator.getPhaseX();
        float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        final RectF circleBox = mChart.getCircleBox();

        final int entryCount = dataSet.getEntryCount();
        final float[] drawAngles = mChart.getDrawAngles();
        final MPPointF center = mChart.getCenterCircleBox();
        final float radius = mChart.getRadius();
        final boolean drawInnerArc = mChart.isDrawHoleEnabled() && !mChart.isDrawSlicesUnderHoleEnabled();
        final float userInnerRadius = drawInnerArc
                ? radius * (mChart.getHoleRadius() / 100.f)
                : 0.f;
        final float roundedRadius = (radius - (radius * mChart.getHoleRadius() / 100f)) / 2f;
        final RectF roundedCircleBox = new RectF();

        int visibleAngleCount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < entryCount; j++) {
            // draw only if the value is greater than zero
            if ((Math.abs(dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j).getY()) > Utils.FLOAT_EPSILON)) {
                visibleAngleCount++;
            }
        }

        final float sliceSpace = visibleAngleCount <= 1 ? 0.f : getSliceSpace(dataSet);
        final Path pathBuffer = new Path();
        final RectF mInnerRectBuffer = new RectF();

        for (int j = 0; j < entryCount; j++) {
            float sliceAngle = drawAngles[j];
            float innerRadius = userInnerRadius;

            Entry e = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j);

            // draw only if the value is greater than zero
            if (!(Math.abs(e.getY()) > Utils.FLOAT_EPSILON)) {
                angle += sliceAngle * phaseX;
                continue;
            }

            // Don't draw if it's highlighted, unless the chart uses rounded slices
            if (mChart.needsHighlight(j) && !drawInnerArc) {
                angle += sliceAngle * phaseX;
                continue;
            }

            final boolean accountForSliceSpacing = sliceSpace > 0.f && sliceAngle <= 180.f;

            mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j));

            final float sliceSpaceAngleOuter = visibleAngleCount == 1 ?
                    0.f :
                    sliceSpace / (Utils.FDEG2RAD * radius);
            final float startAngleOuter = rotationAngle + (angle + sliceSpaceAngleOuter / 2.f) * phaseY;
            float sweepAngleOuter = (sliceAngle - sliceSpaceAngleOuter) * phaseY;

            if (sweepAngleOuter < 0.f) {
                sweepAngleOuter = 0.f;
            }

            pathBuffer.reset();

            float arcStartPointX = center.x + radius * (float) Math.cos(startAngleOuter * Utils.FDEG2RAD);
            float arcStartPointY = center.y + radius * (float) Math.sin(startAngleOuter * Utils.FDEG2RAD);

            if (sweepAngleOuter >= 360.f && sweepAngleOuter % 360f <= Utils.FLOAT_EPSILON) {
                // Android is doing "mod 360"
                pathBuffer.addCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
            } else {
                if (drawInnerArc) {
                    float x = center.x + (radius - roundedRadius) * (float) Math.cos(startAngleOuter * Utils.FDEG2RAD);
                    float y = center.y + (radius - roundedRadius) * (float) Math.sin(startAngleOuter * Utils.FDEG2RAD);

                    roundedCircleBox.set(x - roundedRadius, y - roundedRadius, x + roundedRadius, y + roundedRadius);
                    pathBuffer.arcTo(roundedCircleBox, startAngleOuter - 180, 180);
                }

                pathBuffer.arcTo(
                        circleBox,
                        startAngleOuter,
                        sweepAngleOuter
                );
            }

            // API < 21 does not receive floats in addArc, but a RectF
            mInnerRectBuffer.set(
                    center.x - innerRadius,
                    center.y - innerRadius,
                    center.x + innerRadius,
                    center.y + innerRadius);

            if (drawInnerArc && (innerRadius > 0.f || accountForSliceSpacing)) {

                if (accountForSliceSpacing) {
                    float minSpacedRadius =
                            calculateMinimumRadiusForSpacedSlice(
                                    center, radius,
                                    sliceAngle * phaseY,
                                    arcStartPointX, arcStartPointY,
                                    startAngleOuter,
                                    sweepAngleOuter);

                    if (minSpacedRadius < 0.f)
                        minSpacedRadius = -minSpacedRadius;

                    innerRadius = Math.max(innerRadius, minSpacedRadius);
                }

                final float sliceSpaceAngleInner = visibleAngleCount == 1 || innerRadius == 0.f ?
                        0.f :
                        sliceSpace / (Utils.FDEG2RAD * innerRadius);
                final float startAngleInner = rotationAngle + (angle + sliceSpaceAngleInner / 2.f) * phaseY;
                float sweepAngleInner = (sliceAngle - sliceSpaceAngleInner) * phaseY;
                if (sweepAngleInner < 0.f) {
                    sweepAngleInner = 0.f;
                }
                final float endAngleInner = startAngleInner + sweepAngleInner;

                if (sweepAngleOuter >= 360.f && sweepAngleOuter % 360f <= Utils.FLOAT_EPSILON) {
                    // Android is doing "mod 360"
                    pathBuffer.addCircle(center.x, center.y, innerRadius, Path.Direction.CCW);
                } else {
                    float x = center.x + (radius - roundedRadius) * (float) Math.cos(endAngleInner * Utils.FDEG2RAD);
                    float y = center.y + (radius - roundedRadius) * (float) Math.sin(endAngleInner * Utils.FDEG2RAD);

                    roundedCircleBox.set(x - roundedRadius, y - roundedRadius, x + roundedRadius, y + roundedRadius);

                    pathBuffer.arcTo(roundedCircleBox, endAngleInner, 180);
                    pathBuffer.arcTo(mInnerRectBuffer, endAngleInner, -sweepAngleInner);
                }
            } else {

                if (sweepAngleOuter % 360f > Utils.FLOAT_EPSILON) {
                    if (accountForSliceSpacing) {

                        float angleMiddle = startAngleOuter + sweepAngleOuter / 2.f;

                        float sliceSpaceOffset =
                                calculateMinimumRadiusForSpacedSlice(
                                        center,
                                        radius,
                                        sliceAngle * phaseY,
                                        arcStartPointX,
                                        arcStartPointY,
                                        startAngleOuter,
                                        sweepAngleOuter);

                        float arcEndPointX = center.x +
                                sliceSpaceOffset * (float) Math.cos(angleMiddle * Utils.FDEG2RAD);
                        float arcEndPointY = center.y +
                                sliceSpaceOffset * (float) Math.sin(angleMiddle * Utils.FDEG2RAD);

                        pathBuffer.lineTo(
                                arcEndPointX,
                                arcEndPointY);

                    } else {
                        pathBuffer.lineTo(
                                center.x,
                                center.y);
                    }
                }

            }

            pathBuffer.close();

            mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(pathBuffer, mRenderPaint);

            angle += sliceAngle * phaseX;
        }

        MPPointF.recycleInstance(center);
    }
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
mChart.setRenderer(new RoundedSlicesPieChartRenderer(pieChart, pieChart.getAnimator(), pieChart.getViewPortHandler()));
```

Comment: After this renderer we have a white circle inside the pie chart if we have a hole in it

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you, this drawDataSet() method was actually taken from the super class PieChartRenderer, only that I found out that by changing a certain "+" sign into "-" (or maybe it was the other way around), then the chart would be rendered with both ends correctly rounded.

Comment: in order to not have issue that I described in previous comment, setRenderer must be set first then other logic to mChart. 

Thanks for your code, it's working well

Comment: Is this configurable to accept any border radius value? or does it always draw a semicircle?

Comment: @NachoRamosSánchez Possibly, I guess, somewhere in all those scary calculations. Technically I don't really know what the code does. Like I previously said, this is code I took from the super class and believe it or not, changing a random sign somewhere produced the result I wanted, so I asked no further questions and let it be.